# Class 'App\account' not found in select box

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have a table account with fields name,id I want to show the list in the select box in blade file.shows 'Class 'App\account' not found' in laravel 5.3 even I have included use App/account.what I did wrong.I'n a newbie to laravel

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
 use Illuminate\Support\MessageBag; 
use App\account;
?> 
<?php echo Form::open(['url' => '/formcontroller','enctype'=>'multipart/form-data','files'=>true,'method' => 'post',
            'autocomplete'=>'off','id'=>'request_form']);?>
<div>account
<?php 
     $types=account::pluck('name','id')->all();
    // echo Form::select('account_name', [''=>'Select']+$types,null,['class'=>'selectpicker default']); 
    ?>
</div>
<?php echo Form::close(); ?>
```

Comment: Is your class name account or Account?

Comment: Normally you never do such logic in a view file. you load your `$types` inside the controller and pass them to the view.

Comment: no account is not my class name

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is here:

```
use App\account;
```

class name first character must be in `Capital` case. So it must be like:

```
use App\Account;
```

And its not a good practice to use model functionality inside view, it must be called in controller and the result is passed on to view.

> Eloquent Model Conventions

Now, let's look at an example `Flight` model, which we will use to retrieve and store information from our flights database table:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Flight extends Model
{
    //
}
```

Note that we did not tell Eloquent which table to use for our Flight model. By convention, the "snake case", plural name of the class will be used as the table name unless another name is explicitly specified. So, in this case, Eloquent will assume the Flight model stores records in the  flights table.

**Edit:**

As you have mentioned in comment that you have no model with the specified name, in that case either make the model or use the `query builder` methods like:

```
DB::table('table')->where()->get();
```

Comment: account is my table name

Comment: I just want to display the data in select box for form field

Comment: @user3386779 is your eloquent model named `account` or `Account`?

Comment: I didn't have model for this

Comment: @user3386779 why are you not using `blade`? create a model to make what you want to do much easier.

Answer (score 1):

$types= DB::table('account')->pluck('name','id')->all();